# Which Nvidia driver should I use?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'd like to ask you a question about something in Nvidia driver for my PC.

I tried to install one from the Nvidia website but I ended with a very low screen resolution, which is for laptops. When I open my display configuration there is a rectangle with "laptop" in it.

What may I do ?
Here is a screen-shot of the drivers, which one I should install?

[image]

Comment: Please use a proper question title. It is impossible to determine what your problem is from this title when viewing the home page.

Answer (score 2):

Use the first one if you want the most stable, most tested driver.

Use the second last one if you want a possibly less stable, but more up to date driver, which is updated whenever Nvidia makes a new official driver release. I would recommend this one.

Comment: The problem happens when I install the second one can give me so I wanna be ensure that drive I will install will work good !